# MariaDB Columnstore delete doesn't delete

Tags: mariadb, columnstore

Every night I have a `cron` job that runs to remove some record from a table in `columnstore` table. Since a few days the delete request does not delete anymore. yet when I execute manually it seems OK, but no :

```
select count(*) from TABLE where FIELD1 <> 0 and FIELD2 = 0;
```

`count(*)`

**159040**

1 row in set (0.11 sec)

```
delete from TABLE where FIELD1 <> 0 and FIELD2 = 0 LIMIT 20000;
```

**Query OK, 20000 rows affected** (6.00 sec)

```
select count(*) from TABLE where FIELD1 <> 0 and FIELD2 = 0;
```

`count(*)`

**159040**

1 row in set (0.10 sec)

As you can see above, delete query seems OK but no rows have been removed. :-(

A little help would be welcome

Thanks you all :)

*Mariadb Columnstore version 1.1.2

Comment: Did you COMMIT the DELETE?  Does Columstore have caveats in this area?

Comment: Hi,
no errors, no alerts, the script that run the delete query has worked well for months. I restarted columnstore service and now it works fine again ...

Answer (score 0):

DELETE in CS is effectively an UPDATE. Did you try to update one record? Does it work with LIMIT applied?
I would suggest you to try the latest 1.2.5 though.